# Time-intensive collection processing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, parallel-processing

The code has been vastly simplified, but should serve to illustrate my question.

```
S = ('A1RT', 'BDF7', 'CP09')
for s in S:
    if is_valid(s): # very slow!
        process(s)
```

I have a collection of strings obtained from a site-scrape. (Strings will be retrieved from site-scrapes periodically.) Each of these strings need to be validated, over the network, against a third party. The validation process can be slow at times, which is problematic. Due to the iterative nature of the above code, it may take some time before the last string is validated and processed.

Is there a proper way to parallelize the above logic in Python? To be frank, I'm not very familiar with concurrency / parallel-processing concepts, but it would seem as though they may be useful in this circumstance. Thoughts?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing

Looks like that would work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `concurrent.futures` module is a great way to start work on "embarrassingly parallel" problems, and can very easily be switched between using either multiple processes or multiple threads within a single process.

In your case, it sounds like the "hard work" is being done on other machines over the network, and your main program will spend most of its time waiting for them to deliver results.  If so, threads should work fine.  Here's a complete, executable toy example:

```
import concurrent.futures as cf

def is_valid(s):
    import random
    import time
    time.sleep(random.random() * 10)
    return random.choice([False, True])

NUM_WORKERS = 10  # number of threads you want to run

strings = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_WORKERS) as executor:
    # map a future object to the string passed to is_valid
    futures = {executor.submit(is_valid, s): s for s in strings}
    # `as_complete()` returns results in the order threads
    # complete work, _not_ necessarily in the order the work
    # was passed out
    for future in cf.as_completed(futures):
        result = future.result()
        print(futures[future], result)
```

And here's sample output from one run:

```
g False
i True
j True
b True
f True
e True
k False
h True
c True
l False
m False
a False
s False
v True
q True
p True
d True
n False
t False
z True
o True
y False
r False
w False
u True
x False
```

`concurrent.futures` handles all the headaches of starting threads, parceling out work for them to do, and noticing when threads deliver results.

As written above, up through 10 (`NUM_WORKERS`) `is_valid()` invocations can be active simultaneously.  `as_completed()` returns a future object as soon as its result is ready to retrieve, and the `executor` automatically hands the thread that computed the result another string for `is_valid()` to chew on.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would happen if the "hard work" and wait-time were due to local computations? Would a different approach be needed? If so, why? Sorry for all of the questions, but I'm a bit of a novice in this area.

Comment: Parallel processing is an exceedingly large and complex topic, about which many books have been written.  If you've been doing it full-time for a year, you're still "a novice" ;-)  That said, threads are ineffective for CPU-bound tasks in pure CPython code because of the global interpreter lock (Google on "Python GIL").  In that case, your best first bet would be to use cf's `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead (to use multiple processes instead of multiple threads, so that the GIL becomes a non-issue).

Comment: Ah, thanks so much for the help / insight! I've got to ask, are there any resources you'd personally recommend to get started on the subject?

Comment: @kylemart Sorry to step in. Before diving into overwhelming amount of details, one ought always **first** become fairly sure, what distinguishes a "just"-**`[CONCURRENT]`** system mode-of-operations ( scheduling ) and an indeed true-**`[PARALLEL]`** system operations. This is by far not the same. **Next** one ought always, no exceptions, no excuse, know the costs of going multi-thread / multi-process or whatever else form of processing concurrency one may opt in. Without knowing the costs, one can spend immense efforts on finaly worse performance, than a pure-**`[SERIAL]`** flow of processing.

Comment: Wrong guy to ask.  I've been doing this since the 1980s, when everyone learned from each other via word-of-mouth and many tears ;-)  I have no idea what's available now in the way of introductory material.  But good advice:  unless you want to _implement_ parallel processing gimmicks for others, stick to the highest-level abstraction your language offers.  That's why I steered you to `concurrent.futures` (Python's highest-level parallelism abstraction).  You could learn a great deal from how `cf` is _implemented_ - but it would be pretty much useless low-level knowledge for most people.

Comment: The former starts about here **[parallel-processing]** >>> https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info The latter starts about here **[parallelism-amdahl]** >>> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3 Many projects, even countless examples here, on StackOverflow, finish with asking "Why's my parallel code so slower than the original?", so indeed worth to read twice before cut once. The costs of ( principally ) wrong approach are inadvertently lost and pain remains, after forgetting to first evaluate the re-formulated Amdahl's Law if there is any potential for speedup at all.

Comment: @user3666197, don't scare them needlessly ;-)  The OP's description is of a vanilla load-balancing problem, involving network communication that takes thousands of times longer than anything on the local machine requires.  There aren't significant subtleties in that - they're just trying to get multiple (& potentially long-running) cross-network requests running simultaneously.  Any sane approach should work fine for that.

Comment: **:o)** as a matter of fact you must've been sure on your own the point was more related not to the "just"-`[CONCURRENT]`-friendly case, where indeed many hundreds of [ms] transport latency ( effectively **almost an *eternity*** ) give a forgiving space for latency-masking, but to an expressed wish to read texts on going deep into whatever knowledge base offers ( while the principles were set sharp & strong in early 60-ies last century & many folks 've forgotten 'em in a keen, yet naive rush into a popular topic of "going parallel" ) but NUMA + all kind of overhead costs are always to be paid.